# How can i record 1 MHz signal and do a real-time processing in a PC?

Tags: dsp-core, real-time, analog-to-digital

I have a 1 MHz signal from transducer that needs to be analyzed in real-time condition, so the sampling needs to be more than 2 MHz. It consists of digital filtering, turn into spectogram and feed into a model for prediction. I am still stuck at what the device that sufficient for that task. i have tried to use high speed ADC and arduino, but the arduino cannot send the data to the PC rapidly. is there aother method that i could use?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a market search will identify suitable candidates. This is not a question central to Signal Processing

Comment: I disagree. This is a problem relevant to signal processing engineers which members of our community will be able to help with. A good answer will benefit other visitors to this site. While the question could do with a little more research it does show some effort and should be left open to allow answers to be proposed.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi should have more than enough power to do what you need.

Comment: @MBaz Can a raspberry compute real time a streaming data with rate around 2 MBps? Thanks

Comment: I guess it depends on how much processing you want to do. It should definitiely be able to handle that rate for at least light processing loads. I have used it to stream samples to a USRP at around 1 Msps and it hardly broke a sweat.

Comment: @MBaz well i need to compute the spectogram of the signal then feed it into a neural network model, is the rapsberry sufficient enough?

Comment: It depends on how complex those are and how efficient your implementation is. For $35, it may be worthi it to buy one and run your own tests on it.

Comment: @MBaz thank you so much, i am gonna try that

Answer (score 2):

Stanley is right and what you need is a data acquisition board. Depending on your application concern, you can either buy it from an online store or build your own if you can do so.

If you would like to make it on your own, then as MBaz suggested you can select from mini pc boards such as a sufficient Raspperry pi that can either transmit your grasped data to your PC at ethernet 100T speeds or the Pi itself can also be used to do the whole analysis as MBaz indicated.

Unfortunately, here you cannot find help on the hardware design of such a board....

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, i have tried to build using arduino but stuck for the transmission to PC, can an arduino semd data to PC using ethernet for faster comm? Thanks

Comment: Rpi 3 has 100 Mbit ethernet, you can use it to connect to a PC. You have to code some UDP data transmission (which is not very difficult). Actual bit rate will be lower down to say 25 Mbps which could provide about 8 M samples per second for 8-bit data. Of course the actual performance depends on a lot of factors.